# Is there any way to download pyside 's online document and then convert it to CHM file?

Tags: pyside

pyside 's online document at here
 http://www.pyside.org/docs/pyside/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it for the [PySide 1.0.7 Reference](http://srinikom.github.io/pyside-docs/), which is hosted on github:

https://github.com/srinikom/pyside-docs/archive/gh-pages.zip

(There is also [a version 1.1.0 on a french website](https://deptinfo-ensip.univ-poitiers.fr/ENS/pyside-docs/)
But I didn't find a download link for it.)

Comment: thanks ,I have downloaded it by Wget

Answer (score 3):

Updated version    (v1.2.1).

https://web.archive.org/web/20140809021949/http://seanfisk.com/pyside-docs/pyside/

https://www.mail-archive.com/pyside@qt-project.org/msg01654.html

Answer (score 0):

Everything online can be mirrored so first mirror it with a tool like [httrack](https://www.httrack.com/) or wget.

Downloading all the resources from http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/ to CWD using httrack:

```
httrack http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/ \
−−robots=0 \
−−user−agent "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0" \
--verbose \
+*.js +*.css +*.png +*.gif +*.jpeg +*.jpg \
```

If you want a cross platform format that can be opened and read everywhere i suggest EPUB. [calibre](https://calibre-ebook.com/download) is able to convert HTML to EPUB, mobi, PDF and other popular formats with ease . First add the downloaded resource to calibre library. You need to only add the home page Calibre will follow the links

```
calibredb add index.html
```

Then open calibre and convert it to whatever format you want

[image: calibre_convert]

There's more than one way to skin a cat. When you got data on your hard drive you can use many tools to improve the presentation like using [SIGIL](https://sigil-ebook.com/) to modify epub generated by calibre
You can use [Pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) or other commercial and free/opensource tools also to do the conversion and modification.